# Bi-directional replication SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, replication, bidirectional

I am asking about any useful data or links to get to know about bi-directional replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactional replication with updateable subscriptions is bi-directional replication where both publisher and subscriber can make the changes and the changes are replicated from publisher to subscriber as well from subscriber to publisher

Here are the links for Transactional replication with updateable susbcriptions and also about conflict detection and resolution in this kind of replication

Updatable Subscriptions for Transactional Replication

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151718.aspx